# TinyMCE height on WordPress 4.1+

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, tinymce

Since WordPress 4.1 you can not change default TinyMCE height with this function:

```
function wptiny($initArray){
$initArray['height'] = '600px';
return $initArray; } 

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wptiny');
```

Why? anyone know a better function to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to achieve, but in a plugin:

Wordpress has the function [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). It has an config option textarea_rows. You can use that.